# cudaMallocPitch out of memory

Tags: cuda

I am working with cuda and I need to allocate bytes into memory:

```
cudaMallocPitch( (void **) &query_dev, &query_pitch_in_bytes, max_nb_query_traited * size_of_float, height + ref_width);

in which:

float *query_dev;
size_t query_pitch_in_bytes;
size_t max_nb_query_traited;
int height;
int ref_width
```

But I got "out of memory". Is there a safe way to do with cudaMallocPitch?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And how much memory where you trying to allocate? And how much memory does your graphics card have?

Comment: I was wrong, the problem is not from that memory allocation. it is because of cublas library.

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close since the OP indicated the cause was not related to his question description and yet did not delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because the memory operations in CUDA is blocking, they make a synchronization point. So other errors, if not checked with cudaThreadSynchonize, will seem like errors on the memory calls.

So if an error is received on a memory operation, try to place a cudaThreadSynchronize before it and check the result.